# Client security of Java Web Start

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

I am deploying an application with java web start, but I am encountering a problem.

When I complete the deployment, I replace the `jar` package in client's cache directory with another `jar` package, but the application runs the  latter `jar`. I have configured the security attributes in the `JNLP` file and signed the `jar` package  by `keytools`.I think the `JWS` should check the  `jar` package legitimacy, and it should not run after being changed.

How does the `JWS` checks the local signed `jar` package has been changed?